# Rails mobile omniauth-facebook sign in issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have a mobile version of my rails app and it uses `omniauth-facebook` and devise for authentication. my problem is whenever I login to facebook using the mobile version it doesn't do any callbacks. I've check the log and this is what I got. do you have any why it's not returning any callback from facebook?

**(facebook) Request phase initiated.**

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-10 22:43:48 +0800
```

Comment: Sorry, but what happend exactly? You press login on page, then you get to fb window (not?), get redirected back to your page (not?)

Comment: in the rails log it just says (facebook) Request phase initiated. and nothing happens. but when I try clicking it several times, the callback kick ins.

Comment: Can you attach login button code?

Comment: `<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authirize_path(:facebook) %>`

Comment: never mind I've fixed the issue. there is a js file that is not loaded and the get request to facebook is terminated.

Comment: Hi @mZaragoza, I've noticed that you make plenty of edits that add mostly unnecessary highlighting and `keywords`. Please don't do that, and generally try to make more substantive edits. Thanks!